# For-Next loop not stopping

Tags: vba, ms-access

This seems crazy basic to ask, but I can't figure out what I've done wrong.  Working in Access VBA to loop through an array, but the FOR loop doesn't stop and I get a "Subscript out of range" error.

```
    compStr = "[" & uniqueIDs(0) & "]=" & rs(uniqueIDs(0))
    bnd = UBound(uniqueIDs)
    For i = 1 To bnd
        compStr = compStr & " and [" & uniqueIDs(i) & "]=" & rs(uniqueIDs(i))
    Next i
```

In this example I'm using the loop to build compStr and bnd stores the array size.  uniqueIDs holds 2 records (0-1) and I've confirmed that bnd and UBound(uniqueIDs) value=1.  However the FOR statement continues until i=2 and of course I get an error when it executes uniqueIDs(2) on the 4th line.  What am I missing?  (I've pasted debug window images below)

[image]

Comment: Which line gives you the error? 
I don't have an answer, but I notice you start your For...next loop at 1. You will miss the first entry in your array, which is at index 0.

Comment: Agree with @AlexK. i being set to 2, and then comparing to bnd is how the For loop decides that the loop is over. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: There's no comment from AlexK anymore so I can't see that. I don't miss 0 - you can see the first line of code includes 0 so I start from 1. The question is why does i get to 2 when the for code should preclude that. The error is a result of i=2 and uniqueIDs does not have a 2 item.

Comment: You should _really_ be using `Option Explicit`. I see everything is a variant, and that tends to lead to trouble like this.

Comment: `Subscript out of range` has nothing to do with the loop. You are trying to reference a `uniqueID` element with an index value `i` that doesn't exist. Check the `LBound` and `UBound` of the array, and what you are doing wrong should become obvious.

Comment: For loops don't stop the i variable from getting to 2. Its just that when that happens, the code inside the loop doesn't execute. Can you tell us which line is throwing the error?

Comment: The line throwing the error is the line executing when i=2, namely the reference to uniqueIDs(i)

Comment: @ErikA Option Explicit doesn't apply to For loops, and my issue is that the loop executes code when i>bnd

Comment: @Scott Option explicit definitely applies to for loops.

Comment: Does "rs" (a recordset I assume?) contain a field called "Line ID" ?

Comment: @Eedz yes rs is a recordset and yes it contains fields "Internal ID" and "Line ID" but honestly that variable has no impact on the question.

Comment: Can you set a break point at the line inside the loop, hover over each UniqueIDs(i) and see if one of them says Subscript out of range ?

Comment: @Eedz we are so far out of the scope of the question I'd like it to stop. Your comments aren't helpful and this is a very simple example. The question is i>bnd and yet the For loop is executing the statement. If you recognize the problem in my code or an explanation of the situation, put it in an answer. Otherwise please stop commenting.

Comment: I have seen strange things happening when the code is not compiled manually. Could you do a Debug -> Compile and try again?

Comment: Post the rest of the code so we can see how RS and everything is defined.

Answer (score 3):

I did a test but that successfully ran, see below implementation:

[image]

Regarding above comments on the data types: I understand why people use Variants in Access: this is because often table values are assigned to variables, and only Variant can pick up NULL. However, in your case something forced the string values to be Strings and not Variants - if I used the line commented out, it would yield Variant/Variant(0 to 1), so I used a typed dummy array - I don't know how otherwise get Variant/String(0 to 1).
Nevertheless, there was no error. Did you compile your code with Debug -> Compile? If not, could you do it and re-try? Sometimes this is necessary, otherwise some code segments newly added/removed are just not executing and the previous compiled version of the code (which is stored by Access) is making a total mess.
If it's still not working, I think you should add the rest of the code as others asked in comments to see how the variables are assigned values, and the version of Access you are using.